# Why is qunit test returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, qunit

I have the following function:

```
MarketingHandler = function () {
    return {
        Init: function () {

                $(document).on("click", "#verify .modal-close", function () {
                    tryVerification();
                });


        }

    }

    function tryCommunicationPreferencesInterceptorAfterVerification() {
        var overlayIsNotDismissed = CookieHelper.GetCookie("dismissed-overlay") == null

        if (overlayIsNotDismissed && window.location.pathname === "/Home/") {
            OverlayHelper.Display("save-preferences");
        }
        else if (overlayIsNotDismissed) {
            // do something else 
        }
    }
}();

$(document).ready(function () {
    MarketingHandler.Init();
});
```

I am attempting to write a test which shows that `OverlayHelper.Display("save-preferences");` is called when it is supposed to be. Here is my attempt:

```
QUnit.test("Test", function (assert) {
    MarketingHandler.Init();
    if (CookieHelper.GetCookie("dismissed-overlay") != null) {
        CookieHelper.DeleteCookie("dismissed-overlay");
    }

    sinon.stub(window.location, 'pathname').returns("/Home/");
    var displayOverlaySpy = sinon.spy(OverlayHelper, 'Display');

    var $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
    $fixture.append(HTMLInjector());
    $('#verify .modal-close').click();

    assert.ok(displayOverlaySpy.calledOnceWith("save-preferences"), "overlay shown");
    displayOverlaySpy.restore();
});

function HTMLInjector() {
    return "<input type='hidden' id='verify .modal-close'/>"
}
```

However I am getting 'expected true, result false' in my tests. Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong here?

Comment: Wondering if you calling `Init()` twice might have something to do with it... oh, also, the `tryVerification` method does not exist? Should that be `tryCommunicationPreferencesInterceptorAfterVerification` ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that the click event is triggered asynchronously and the assert happens before the click happens. I think you could use something like the following to work around the issue.

```
var done = assert.async();
var $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
$fixture.append(HTMLInjector());
$('#verify .modal-close').click();

setTimeout(function() {
    assert.ok(displayOverlaySpy.calledOnceWith("save-preferences"), "overlay shown");
    done();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this resulted in "Test took longer than 30000ms; test timed out." @ZeninEasaPanthakkalakath

Comment: Could you add in a breakpoint and manually verify if things are working the way you intent? For instance, some variables or functions could be undefined inside the test.